# I want to search an user keyword from array stored in a json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

This is the output:

```
[{"houseName":"a","houseType":"b","houseFloors":"c","houselocation":"d"},{"houseName":"p","houseType":"q","houseFloors":"r","houselocation":"s"}]
```

My code is as:

```
<html lang>
<head>
<title>JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>House Name:
  <input type='text' name='houseName' id='houseName' placeholder="House Name">
</label>
<br>
<br>
<label>House type:
  <input type='text' name='houseType' id='houseType' placeholder="House type">
</label>
<br>
<br>
<label>House Floors:
  <input type='text' name='houseFloors' id='houseFloors' placeholder="House Floors">
</label>
<br>
<br>
<label>House Location:
  <input type='text' name='houselocation' id='houselocation' placeholder="House Location">
</label>
<br>
<br>

<button type="button" id="add">Add Details</button>
<button type="button" id="print">Show</button>

<pre></pre>
<script>
    var list = [],
  $ins = $('#houseName, #houseType, #houseFloors, #houselocation'),
  var counter = {
    houseName: {},
    houseType: {},
    houseFloors: {},
    houselocation: {}
  };

 $('#add').click(function() {
  var obj = {},
    valid = true;
  $ins.each(function() {
    var val = this.value;
    if (val) {
      obj[this.id] = val;
    } else {

      alert(" Cannot be blank");

      return false;
    }
  });
  if (valid) {
    list.push(obj);
    $ins.val('');

  }
});

$('#print').click(function() {
  $('pre').text(JSON.stringify(list) + '\n\n');

})


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Now what i want is when a user provides a keyword, i want to search that particular keyword through this output in javascript and return the complete details of that particular object.

Ex:If keyword is : a
the output should be:
[{"houseName":"a","houseType":"b","houseFloors":"c","houselocation":"d"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should work

```
var arr = [{"houseName":"a","houseType":"b","houseFloors":"c","houselocation":"d"},{"houseName":"p","houseType":"q","houseFloors":"r","houselocation":"s"}]


function queryObject(prop, key)  {
var returnThis;
for(var i=0, len = arr.length; i< len; i++) {

if(arr[i][prop] === key) {
returnThis = arr[i]
} 
return returnThis
}
}
$('input').on('change', function() {
var prop = $(this).attr('id');
var key = $(this).val();
queryObject(prop,key)
});
```

Comment: I tried this,but didn't work out. I m sharing a friddle. can u plz look......https://jsfiddle.net/gaan10/mvoheo80/

Comment: i want to search based on user input.

Comment: search where exactly ? you have to have some data first

Comment: yes,when u enter data and click add details.Its stored in an object.when u click show it shows ur entered data one by one .So i need to search from here .

Answer (score 0):

For a generic solution, simply do a filter over your `output` array

```
var keyword = "a";
var result = output.filter( function(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj).filter( function(key){
    return obj[ key ].indexOf( keyword ) != -1;
  }).length > 0;
});

//now result has the filtered array
console.log( result );
```

**DEMO**

```js
var output = [{"houseName":"a","houseType":"b","houseFloors":"c","houselocation":"d"},{"houseName":"p","houseType":"q","houseFloors":"r","houselocation":"s"}];

var keyword = "a";
var result = output.filter( function(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj).filter( function(key){
    return obj[ key ].indexOf( keyword ) != -1;
  }).length > 0;
});

//now result has the filtered array
console.log( result );
```

Comment: If i put a input keyword from a search box will it work

Comment: @gaan10 if you can put that textbox value in `keyword`, then it will work.

Comment: This is my modification.I am sending the input from the search . function sendToPage(){
    var input = document.getElementById("search").value;

var result = output.filter( function(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj).filter( function(key){
    return obj[ key ].indexOf( input ) != -1;
  }).length > 0;
});


//now result has the filtered array
document.write( result );
}

Comment: @gaan10 are you returning result from `sendToPage()` method? Otherwise you will need to check its value only inside this method.

Comment: @gaan10 then it should work. What issue are you facing after this?

Comment: Not getting the searched result, Can i send my edits.

Comment: @gaan10 your fiddle is not working. Also your `button type` needs to be `button` instead of `submit` for `search`.

Comment: in mine its working.Apart from the input whats wrong with search

Comment: @gaan10 if it is working for you other than search, then simply try making button type as `button`

Comment: After adding click show to get the details.The friddle works apart from search.......https://jsfiddle.net/gaan10/dbesd825/1/

Comment: @gaan10 check the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dbesd825/2/ you needed to use `list` instead of `output` in the method

Comment: thanks so much   @gurvinder372.Can u explain these lines please.      return Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key) {
          return obj[key].indexOf(input) != -1;
        }).length > 0;